# Illegal character in .p2 path

Tags: eclipse, maven, p2

I recently started getting the following error in my Eclipse console when I launch a child runtime from my Eclipse development setup.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 20: file:/C:/Users/Steve Vestal/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.18.3.20220227-1319/jars/
```

At roughly the same time, running an m2e maven build configuration in the parent development Eclipse started getting the following error in the console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/internal/InternalFutureFailureAccess
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling m2e.  I tried opening Oomph in expert mode and running the .p2 analyzer, which detected no errors in the repository.

Do you have any ideas about what else to try?  What happens if I just delete the jars in that .p2 m2e folder?  A build using an external (not in Eclipse) maven tool does still work, would that replace any deleted m2e items?

Comment: It is a bug, the space in your name is causing the issue - change your username without a space :) . Or file a bug report :)

Comment: How do you launch the child runtime? Probably, the space in the URI at index 20 has to be `%20`.